# String to byte hex convert

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I would like to ask a question about string convert to byte from windows form, i have try several ways to do these, while convert string to hex is successful turn to string but the problem i need to turn it back to hex byte because the API only get bytes.

Here is the convert below:

```
string getTxtString = txtString.text;
int convertToInt = int32.Parse(getTxtString);
string hexString = convertToInt.toString("X");
```

// i have try with X2 it will get two digit for example 0A

How to convert to **Hex** byte in situation like this or please provide other solution.

For example:
11  =  0A

0A is the conversion of below:

```
 int convertToInt = int32.Parse(getTxtString);
 string hexString = convertToInt.toString("X2");
```

From the convert above will only get 0A.
The Api need to whole **Hex** value like 0x0A, i need to send 0x0A to API.

Comment: `byte result = Convert.ToByte(hexString, 16);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko it get integer but i need hex value in order to send it to API

Comment: I'm sorry; if you want just one `byte` it should be `Convert.ToByte`

Comment: I am a little confused. Is your desired conversion from `int` to `byte`? Your text does not match your snippet ...

Comment: `11 = 0A`? Typo?

Comment: What do you mean by "hex byte"? A byte is an 8-bit numerical value, while hex is a string representation of that number

Comment: @Fildor   so sorry i don't write the question well, question already update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Convert.ToByte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobyte?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToByte_System_String_System_Int32_) while providing `fromBase` (`16` in your case)

```
 // "0A" (string) -> 0x0A == 10 == 0b00001010 (byte)
 byte result = Convert.ToByte(hexString, 16);

 ...

 SomeApiMethod(..., result, ...);
```

In case you have a `Int32` encoded in fact (e.g. `"FF120A"`) and you want to get the *last byte*:

```
 // "FF120A" (or "0xFF120A") -> 0xFF120A (int) -> 0x0A (byte)
 // unchecked - we don't want OverflowException on integer overflow
 byte result = unchecked((byte)Convert.ToInt32(hexString, 16));

 ...

 SomeApiMethod(..., result, ...);
```

Please, notice that the `byte` (e.g. `0x0A`) is always *the same*, it its *string representation* that can *vary*:

```
 // 00001010 - binary
 Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(result, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')); 
 // 10       - decimal
 Console.WriteLine(result);  
 // 0A       - hexadecimal
 Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("X2"));
```

Comment: thanks you for the quick reply answer, in my situation the API only receive byte, i need to convert the string to int32 or ToString ("X2") to get hexadecimal value, from you answer is it just use string byte to get the convert value to API?

Comment: @Victor: you have a `string` which represents some integer value (e.g. "FF120A") and the API wants `byte` (e.g. `0x0A == 10 = 0b00001010`) not its *string representation*. If you can guarantee that the `string` is `byte` - put `Convert.ToByte`; if not - you have to add *cast*: `unchecked((byte)Convert.ToInt32(...)`

Comment: @ Dmitry Bychenko thanks for advice, i try to use int or byte to convert string that i have for example "0x0A" , it show format error, but why?

Comment: @Victor: what is the code which cause the error, please?

Comment: int getbyte = convert.ToByte (string) or byte getbyte = convert.ToByte(string), i feel like i was wrong right?

Comment: @Victor: you have to put `16` **explicitly** `int getbyte = Convert.ToInt32 (string, 16);` or `byte getbyte = Convert.ToByte (string, 16);` please, have a look at my code in the answer

Comment: you're right, thanks for your advice if i have any byte convert problem can i just ask you directly please?

Comment: @Victor: you are welcome! But when asking, please, provide some *examples* (say, "I have `"0x84523A0"` and I want to extract the last `0xA0` byte")

Comment: i have a question how to convert string[]{"123","123","234","456","542","245","143","123","126","899","231","144"} to 
byte[] convertbyte = {123,123,234,456,542,245,245,143,123,126,899,231,144}

Comment: @Victor: Technically `byte[] convertbyte = source.Select(item => byte.Parse(item)).ToArray();`; but as we can see some values are *invalid*: `"456"`, `"542"` (`byte` **must** be in the `[0..255]` **range**) and we are going to have an exception thrown

Comment: i have change the way to get the string it come from textbox, i use string[] getAllText = {Block_1,Block_2,Block_3,Block_4,Block_5,Block_6,Block_7,Block_8,Block_9,Block_10,Block_11,Block_12}
foreach(string combinetxt in getAllText) { convertByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(combinetxt);}
it prevent the out of range problem and  has problem here need to make them into byte[] convertbyte  = {123,123,234,456,542,245,245,143,123,126,899,231,144}

Comment: your solution might can use i will figure it out, mine is worst thank you for your solution